# Multichannel configuration in hyperledger fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

How to setup multi channel configuration in fabric? Is it possible to get data from channel in which the peer is joined?

I have created 2 channels named channel1 and channel2. 
Peer0 and peer1 - joined in all channels
Peer2 and peer3 - Joined in channel1
Peer4 and Peer5 - Joined in channel2

expected result is :

Peer0 and Peer1 can able to see the data from channel1 and channel2.
Peer2 and Peer3 can only see the data from channel1.
Peer4 and Peer5 can only see the date from channel2.

Answer (score 0):

---

Hyperledger Fabric recommends extending the network with adding and creating rest of the members Orgs, consortia and its channels after the administrative (default) network is constructed.

You can get that information and samples from "[Blockchain network](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/network/network.html)" (It shows you build order in turn.) or [BYFN tutorial](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials.html). It will be easier than finding how to build "Multichannel Network" at once.

---

Anyway, at the first, your channel-configuration (e.g., configtx.yaml) has to get two consortia definition. Because of that a consortium refer to a channel how many (or which) organizations participate. It means that a channel is created by defining a consortium.

In your case, let's assume that you define 3 ORGs and 6 peers (Or, a lot of different types of the network model you can define.);

- ORG1 contributes 2 peers as peer0 and peer1
- ORG2 contributes 2 peers as peer2 and peer3
- ORG3 contributes 2 peers as peer4 and peer5

Consortia will be defined as below (This is not full code exactly right, it is just a sample to know how we approach for...)

--- configtx.yaml ---

```
Profiles:
  OrgsOrdererGenesis:

    ...

    Consortiums:
      # refer to channel1
      ConsortiumOne:
        Organizations:
          - ORG1
          - ORG2

      # refer to channel2
      ConsortiumTwo:
        Organizations:
          - ORG1
          - ORG3

    ...

  channel1:
    Consortiums: ConsortiumOne
    Application:
      <<: *ApplicationDefaults
      Organizations:
        - ORG1
        - ORG2

  channel2:
    Consortiums: ConsortiumTwo
    Application:
      <<: *ApplicationDefaults
      Organizations:
        - ORG1
        - ORG3
    ...
```

In another case, we will approach with just a consortium;

```
Profiles:
  OrgsOrdererGenesis:

    ...

    Consortiums:
      ConsortiumAll:
        Organizations:
          - ORG1
          - ORG2
          - ORG3

    ...

  channel1:
    Consortiums: ConsortiumAll
    Application:
      <<: *ApplicationDefaults
      Organizations:
        - ORG1
        - ORG2

  channel2:
    Consortiums: ConsortiumAll
    Application:
      <<: *ApplicationDefaults
      Organizations:
        - ORG1
        - ORG3
    ...
```

By the channel policies, you have to then implement joining appropriate peers to each channel created. We can not delve into the detail of the building multichannel at this comment in turn. See this [multichannel design document](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1eRNxxQ0P8yp4Wh__Vi6ddaN_vhN2RQHP-IruHNUwyhc/edit#heading=h.hml58k6zw29h), it will be helpful for you. Or, it will be better to dive in detail into fundamental information Hyperledger Docs supported.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool can help you to generate your expected Hyperledger fabric network more easily. [networkLancher](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-test/tree/master/tools/NL)

Like Peter mentioned above, you can define your network participants whatever you want and than arrange the participants to join the desired channel.

So this tools can generate the crypto material and the docker-compose by just input few command lines. Besides, `network.json` can help your to config the environment parameters, container connection...

Here is an example to create a 2 channel Hyperledger fabric network, with 3 Orgs and 3 peers pre Orgs:

```
./networkLauncher.sh -o 3 -x 3 -r 3 -p 3 -k 3 -z 3 -n 2 -t kafka -f test
```

Hope this can help.